# Pagemethod is throwing 'A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'

Tags: ajax, asmx, pagemethods

I have seen so many post on this error explaining about JSON issues. I am just having a classic web form that calls a web method. I have a bunch of radio buttons and 2 drop downs in a form. once I check one of the radio button and two of the drop downs, I have to click on `Build template` button to populate the form (basically am email form with to, cc, subject field and so on)

When I select the first radio button and then the drop downs, I get the required results. But when I select any of the other radio buttons that return data, I get this circular reference error. The last radio button does not return data, so it doesn't throw the serialization error.

Here is the javascript that calls the page method

```
function HandleIT() {
    var ServiceID = document.getElementById("<%=ddServiceList.ClientID%>").value;
    var Status;

    // #code to set the drop downs to 1,2,3,4,5 on 'checked'# removed

    PageMethods.FindAllRecipient(ServiceID, Status, onSucess, onError);

    function onSucess(result) {
        document.getElementById("<%=txtTo.ClientID%>").value = result[0];
        document.getElementById("<%=txtCC.ClientID%>").value = result[1];
    }

    function onError(result) {
        alert('Something wrong.');
    }
}
```

Here is the code in server method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object[] FindAllRecipient(string serviceID, string currentStatus)
{
    RemoteObj1 = new ServiceEmailer();
    Object[] results = RemoteObj1.FindAllRecipients(
        Convert.ToInt16(serviceID),
        Convert.ToInt16(currentStatus));

    return results;
}
```

The code works fine in the server method. So no issues there. As the error says obviously, the issue is while serializing and returning the results.

Comment: Do you really feel that _all_ of that code is necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for editing my post John. Sorry for not being brief. I thought that would be easier. i have removed unncessary tags and designs.

Comment: The easiest is to post the smallest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok. I think the page itself is unncessary. I also tried changing it from array of objects to array of strings. I still get the same circular reference. I dont understand why there would be a circular reference for all other radio buttons except for the first one. When I continue wiout breaking at the error, the first radio buton still works and calls 'onsuccess'

Comment: thanks for your help. I couldnt figure out the issue. So I did a work around to concatenate the results into a single string with a delimiter on the server side and split it using javascript at the client side.